# Can't hit Controller with form due to TeamRequest instead of Request in parameters

Tags: php, laravel, request

In a form, I have:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>URL::action("TeamController@store",$tournament->slug)]) !!}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When I it click on it, I don't enter into TeamContoller@Store

```
public function store(TeamRequest $request, Tournament $tournament)
```

But if I change TeamRequest to Request, now it works...

Here is the TeamRequest:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

class TeamRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'championship_id' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Why is it happening????

Comment: When you say you don't enter into the `store` method, where _do you_ go? Errors? Another method?

Comment: nowhere, but I fixed it, will post the answer! Tx

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding :

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

int my TeamRequeset file